# Finding a value in object by equating from array of object and replacing it with new one from the same collection of array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, replace

I have an array of object and an Oject of Objects:

```
let newSet = [{
    "newName": "New One",
    "oldName": "old one"
  },
  {
    "newName": "New two",
    "oldName": "old two"
  },
  {
    "newName": "New Three",
    "oldName": "old three"
  }
];

let property = {
  companies: [{
    products: [{
        lob: {
          description: "old two"
        }
      },
      {
        lob: {
          description: "old three"
        }
      }
    ]
  }]
};
```

Now here what I am trying is to check if `property` object has the `lob's description` value as on of the `oldName` from `newSet` array, then it should get replaced with `newName` of same object from `newSet` array

Expected output:

```
let property = {
  companies: [{
    products: [{
        lob: {
          description: "New two"
        }
      },
      {
        lob: {
          description: "New Three"
        }
      }
    ]
  }]
};
```

NOTE: There could be multiple companies and their multiple products into it

Comment: _"... and an Oject of Objects"_ - `companies` and `products` should also be arrays instead of objects

Comment: @Andreas ohh yes they are thanks for correcting me and updating it

Comment: can you also share the expected output? btw what have you tried?

Comment: @gorak updated with expected results

Comment: Just build an object map out of new set with oldname as key and newname as value, replace all descriptions by object map key,value mapping

Comment: @Andreas I have use this format from console, you are right on that part as well, I dont need numeric representation there, removed numeric representations from it

Answer (score 0):

Create object map `{[oldName]: newName}` from newSet.
Iterate through all companies and products for each company, find description in object map and replace with newName value if it exists.

```js
const map = Object.fromEntries(newSet.map(({oldName,newName})=>[oldName,newName]))
for(const {products} of property.companies)
  for(const {lob} of products)
    if(map[lob.description])
      lob.description = map[lob.description]

console.log(property)
```

```html
<script>
  let newSet = [{
      "newName": "New One",
      "oldName": "old one"
    },
    {
      "newName": "New two",
      "oldName": "old two"
    },
    {
      "newName": "New Three",
      "oldName": "old three"
    }
  ];

  let property = {
    companies: [{
      products: [{
          lob: {
            description: "old two"
          }
        },
        {
          lob: {
            description: "old three"
          }
        }
      ]
    }]
  };
</script>
```

Comment: I ended up into a linting error saying: `Assignment to property of function parameter`, ofcourse doing this is a bad thing in JS, any other away I can assign this?

Comment: You should look up what that actually means.  Adhering to your style guidelines is something you need to understand.  It's a trivial change.  The intent of that safety guideline for that eslint rule clearly isn't applicable to what the code is doing.  If you need immutability, that is something you will also need to account for.